# Python - Most efficient way to define a piecewise function

Tags: python, performance, function, piecewise

I have a piecewise mathematical function that needs to be evaluated a lot of times, as a subfunction in `quad` and `curve_fit` routines. In trying to improve the performance of my program, I found that a lot of time was spent in evaluating conditions in the `if` statements.

My function looks like :

```
def myfunc(x):
    if x < x0:
        return 0.
    elif x < x1:
        return func1(x)
    elif x < x2:
        return c2
    else:
        return 0.

def func1(x):
    return c1*((math.cos(x)/math.cos(x2))**2 - 1)**0.5
```

Is there a way to define the same function to reduce the function evaluation time?

note:

```
x0 < x1 < x2
c1, c2 are constants
```

Comment: what are the values of x, x0, x1, x2?

Comment: what is the ordering of x0,x1,x2

Comment: The function call overhead should dwarf these evaluations? How did you work out that the function _body_ is the bottleneck? Have you used `line_profiler`?

Comment: there are 4 cases, you need 4 tests...

Comment: @roganjosh : I used cProfile. `tottime` (which excludes subfunction calls) is a significant portion of `cumtime`.

Comment: maybe nested ternary would be faster...

Comment: Can you reduce your problem to barebones? I guess you're using something based on numpy/scipy in which case you should have no need to call a python function for something like this. If you're calling this function on an array then for sure the `numpy` tag would get you a vectorised approach. As it is, we don't have full context.

Comment: Depending on the value of x, x0, x1, x2, is it possible to use a dictionary/look-up-table?

Comment: You can't make a significant change in performance by changing the function's body, by only using pure python (Even if you can reduce the number of comparisons). But as you're stated, if the function is getting called many times or repeatedly, you can use memoizing by decorating your function with a [`functools.lru_cache()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) function. Otherwise, as mentioned in other comment you'd better to use Numpy (if it's possible) or other high performance libraries as such.

Comment: @roganjosh : I added the definitions of `func1` and `func2`, which is a constant. I used `numpy.cos` before, but `math.cos` seems to be a lot faster.

Comment: @FredrikPihl :  I had something like that in mind. I know it is possible if the choices are exact (for example `if a == 'hello': ...`). But I don't know how to do it with comparison tests on floats.